# The problem of annotation format of @JsonFormat

Tags: java

The back-end entity class uses @ jsonformat annotation, but there seems to be a problem with the time format in 24-hour and 12 hour when the front-end gets data. For example, the back-end time is 2021-5-21 00:50, but the time sent to the front-end becomes 2021-5-21 12:50. Is there a problem with the property setting of @ jsonformat or the front end.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm",timezone="GMT+8")
```

Comment: Refer to: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/). `hh` - (1-12), `HH` - (0-24).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment, you just need to change the lower capital format `hh` (which converts hours in 12h format "1-12") to the upper capital `HH` (which converts hours in 24h format "0-24"), so your entire date time format should appear like this:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",timezone="GMT+8")
```

I personally use a the `@JsonSerializer` and `@JsonDeserializer` annotations to realize more efficient conversion patterns, but I think in your case is not necessary.